# Using Apple's white tab bar in my app

Tags: ios, user-interface

Can the tab bar used in Apple apps, such as Music, be used in my iOS app? Is there a way to call it up without creating my own background?

Comment: App specific styles like this aren't part of the core OS.  You would need to create your own similar one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking to do is change the navigation bar or tabbar color.  You can do something like this to change the color of your navigation bar /tabbar anywhere that it appears in your app via the appearance proxy.  Although this method only works for iOS 5 and greater.

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

or

```
 [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

or if you need to target iOS4 or lower / need to apply the color changes to specific viewcontrollers and not globally, you could do something like this:

```
 currentViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

and of course, if you need more specific color values than these presets ( like `[UIColor whiteColor]`), you can always refer to the `UIColor` documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  for more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely a custom tabbar which you will need to build yourself. `UITabbar` has a `tintColor` property that you can utilize as well.

Check out this tutorial on how to [Customize the Tab bar](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-how-to-customize-tab-bar-background-appearance/).

Comment: I actually followed that tutorial, but wanted to use the one in the Music app. Eh, I'll live. Thanks!